# How to remove an element from an (nested) array via a (lodash) path expression in a immutable way?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to remove an element from an array within a object via a **path expression** in a immutable way / while preserving the original object and just changing the changed object on the path.

So I try to have some method like:

```
const doc = {a: ['a', 'b']};
const newDoc = removeAt('a[0]', doc);
```

Where after execution newDoc is {a: ['b']}; and doc remains as it is.

I tried around with lodash with some success, but it really sucks how I need to set it up. Has anyone an idea how to 'just remove' that element without all those intermediate steps?

```js
function removeAt(path, obj) {
  const arrayPath = _.initial(_.toPath(path));
  const arrayIndex = _.last(_.toPath(path));
  const [array] = _.at(obj, [arrayPath]);
  const newArray = _.concat(_.slice(array, 0, arrayIndex), _.slice(array, arrayIndex + 1));
  const newObj = _.setWith(_.clone(obj), arrayPath, newArray, _.clone);
  return newObj;
}

const doc = {
  'stringList': ['a', 'b'],
  'container': {
    objectList: [{
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b'
    }, {
      c: 'c',
      d: 'd'
    }]
  }
};
const path = 'container.objectList.[0]';
const newDoc = removeAt(path, doc);

console.log('old doc and new newDoc:', {
  doc,
  newDoc
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

My removeAt works (and keeps stringList to contain the very same object), but is way to complex.. :-/ I am looking for a cleaner way to remove those contents. Most lovely would be with lodash, lodash fp or plain JS ;-)

With immutable way I mean that I need to have changed nothing in the source object but generate a new Object with exactly those objects on the path to the deleted entry changed. So that I have as few new objects as possible. I need that for react to have a quick way to check if anything has changed and if it needs to redraw a part of it's UI tree, which should be reduced to just the changed parts.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you either have to clone and remove, or assemble and omit. There is no "built-in" way to directly do this without writing your own function.

Comment: lodash has a built-in `_.get(obj, path` function. Can you just clone the object, get the array, and then remove the element?

Comment: @TheCrzyMan Omit seems to be deprecated, will be removed in lodash 5 (See [Issue 2930](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2930) ). And even if it would be an option, omit did not work on arrays in my first tests. I am cloning, reassembling and whatever with that code, but it seems like such a general use case, that I thought that there should be a shorter/leaner solution.

Comment: HA! I didn't even think to look for a `_.omit()`! That's awesome! But sad to see it go. My suggestion would be to format it more like my answer, where you clone, and then manually remove the element from the array via a specialized function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [lodash.remove](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#remove) with [lodash.set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#set)

In your case, you can try doing something like

```
const doc = {a: ['a', 'b']};
const newDoc = _.set(doc, 'a', _.remove(doc.a, (v,i) => i !== 0 ));
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not work with paths and it mutates the source object as it directly removes the elements from the array. See [remove](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove) docs: *this method mutates array*

Comment: Do you want the complete object to be cloned or just unmutated arrray? Also why not use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)?

Comment: Array.splice does mutate the source array. I thought the word immutable would be clear, but as it seams it isn't :-( Sorry about that. I elaborated on what I understand by immutable in my question just now: *With immutable way I mean that I need to have changed nothing in the source object but generate a new Object with exactly those objects on the path to the deleted entry changed. So that I have as few new objects as possible.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know lodash, but it apparently does have a built in [get(obj, path)](https://lodash.com/docs#get).
So, if you are only removing elements from arrays, the following will get that array and then remove an element by its index (with no checking). All without mutating the source object.

```js
const doc = {
  'stringList': ['a', 'b'],
  'container': {
    objectList: [{
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b'
    }, {
      c: 'c',
      d: 'd'
    }]
  }
};

function removeElement(obj, pathToArr, index){
  // I don't know of a better way to clone, according to flob, this doesn't play well with React
  //const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const clone = _.clone(obj);
  const arr = _.get(clone, pathToArr);
  arr.splice(index, 1);
  return clone;
}

console.log(removeElement(doc, "container.objectList", 0));
```

Comment: _.get is somewhat shorter, but it just saves one array over _.at, so it's no real improvement in my eyes. And that clone would you do would cause my whole (React) UI to readraw as it would recreate all those hundreds of inputs and would be very slow (due to copy&redraw). So it's not a real option :-/

Comment: @flob Gotcha. I also don't know anything about React. Looking into your answer some more, I gather that the main difference is that I use splice and you concat two slices. would `_.cloneDeep(obj)` work?

Comment: That might clone faster, but would still clone the whole object tree. I tried to be more elaborate on what I understand by an immutable way :-) I need to have changed nothing in the source object but exactly those objects on the path to the deleted entry. So that I have as few new objects as possible...

Comment: @flob I'm interpreting what you are saying in two ways: 1) you want to mutate the original object but only along the path to the nested object. 2) you want to create a new object that only has the nested objects that lead directly to the object you want to mutate.

Comment: Sorry for beeing not precise enough :-) I want the original object not to be mutated at all and the new object to contain as much as possible of the old object. By which I mean that anything that hasn't changed should be taken from the old object.

Comment: @flob In that case, I guess I can't suggest anything really better than what I have already submitted. I updated the cloning to use lodash. Our answers are functionally similar. Mine just fits better with how my brain works. Both have their pros and cons. Your's is more straight forward to use in regard to its parameters, but you need to assemble a new string if you ever want to remove at a different index. Mine is a bit less verbose internally and you can cherry pick an index without needing to assemble a new string, but is much less straight forward in regards to its parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) I have all those strings in our ever changing metadata model for the rendered form, so I'll stick to that solution for now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your function as such, using :

`_.cloneDeep` to not mutate original object

`_.unset` an element from an array within a object via a path expression

`_.set` new `_.compact`ed array

```js
function removeAt(path, index, obj) {
  var res = _.cloneDeep(obj);
  _.unset(res, path+'['+index+']');
  _.set(res, path, _.compact(_.get(res, path)));

  return res;
}

const doc = {
  'stringList': ['a', 'b'],
  'container': {
    objectList: [{
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b'
    }, {
      c: 'c',
      d: 'd'
    }]
  }
};
const path = 'container.objectList';
const newDoc = removeAt(path, 0,  doc);

console.log(doc, newDoc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: @yvoytivycg Thanks for your effort. But 1. I don't want to clone the whole object, 2. I don't want to remove anything that is falsy, just the provided path. So your solution won't work :-/

Comment: @flob If you don't want to mutate the original object, how do expect to do this without cloning or making a copy?

Comment: @BenSmith I don't want to clone the whole object, just the parts that are different. If you run the code snippte in my question you see some comments like `/**ref:7**/` (maybe only on chrome) which show that only the changed parts of the objects are new and that all other parts are referencing to their original state. That way react pure components can detect change quite fast :-)